# Attribute information gain

Tags: r, weka

I am an R user and I am interested in finding out the most significant/important attributes/predictors for classifier `Naive Bayes Multinomial` with package `Rweka`.

I am aware of the function `InfoGainAttributeEval`. But this function uses the filter approach to attribute selection. So it is classifier independent.

I would like a classifier dependent evaluation. So I tried `WrapperSubsetEval`. Here is what I did:

```
library("RWeka")

DT <-
  data.frame(
    sex = as.character(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)),
    att1 = as.character(c(4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2)),
    att2 = as.character(c(4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 7, 6, 7, 8, 9)))

WSE <- make_Weka_filter("weka/attributeSelection/WrapperSubsetEval")

WSE(sex ~ att1 + att2,
    data = DT,
    control = Weka_control(
      B = list("weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes")))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in .jcall(filter, "Z", "setInputFormat", instances) : 
  method setInputFormat with signature (Lweka/core/Instances;)Z not found
```

I have completely no idea about this error. Is it a weka problem? Or R problem? Or is it just syntax error?

Thank you in advance for any help. I would still like to have your kind assistant if you have any insight for this problem.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?